# Can not add static route in my Ubuntu, SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable

Tags: openvpn, vpn, route

I'm trying to add a static route in my VPS to a client that is on the other side of the VPN tunnel to my VPS and forwards it's traffic through the tunnel.

This is the setup of my destination that I'm planning to add a route to. The Raspi acts as a router which itself is connected to an AP and the NAS is connected to Raspi and redirects its traffic through the VPN tunnel:

```
                                        +--------------------------------+
                                        |            Raspi               |
                      (192.168.0.101/24)|                                |(192.168.1.1/24)
 (192.168.0.1/24) AP<>=================={wlan0                       eth0}================<>NAS (192.168.1.102/24)
                                        |   \                        /   |
                                        |    +----------------------+    |
                                        |    |     iptables and     |    |
                                        |    |    routing engine    |    |
                                        |    +-----------+----------+    |
                                        |                |               |
                                        |             {tun0}             |
                                        |            10.8.0.6            |
                                        +--------------------------------+
```

I'm trying to do `route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.8.0.6`, in order to communicate with my NAS behind the Raspi, but it I get `SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable`.

These are the server side info:

$ ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
          inet addr:217.B.C.D  Bcast:217.B.C.D  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: XXXX::XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/XX Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1598 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1453 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:176137 (176.1 KB)  TX bytes:165179 (165.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:460 (460.0 B)  TX bytes:460 (460.0 B)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:169 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:14825 (14.8 KB)  TX bytes:15071 (15.0 KB)
```

$ netstat -anr

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.255.255.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
10.255.255.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
```

$ ip route list

```
default via 10.255.255.1 dev eth0
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0
10.8.0.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.1
10.255.255.1 dev eth0  scope link
```

**Additional info:**

If you are wondering how I've acheived the traffic redirection between the interfaces, here is my post describing how I've managed everything up to this point using iptables:

[Redirect secondary network interface traffic along with port forwarding to tun0 (OpenVPN) using iptables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273926/redirect-secondary-network-interface-traffic-along-with-port-forwarding-to-tun0)

Client netwrok block (in case of **p2p topology**):

```
10.8.0.4 : Network address
10.8.0.5 : Virtual remote endpoint; Non pingable; Only used for routing
10.8.0.6 : Client IP address
10.8.0.7 : Network broadcast address
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I've changed my VPN server configuration to `topology subnet` and `ifconfig-push 10.8.0.6 255.255.255.0` in the corresponding `ccd` file for the VPN client to bring the VPN server and client into the `/24` subnet instead of `/32` and then add the routes. This time `route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.8.0.6` or `route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev tun0` returned no errors, however still no `ping 192.168.1.102`. `netstat -anr` changed though (in case of `route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.8.0.6`).

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.255.255.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
10.255.255.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     10.8.0.6        255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
```

Comment: How far does a traceroute 192.168.1.102 get?

Comment: No far... Returns * * * from the very beginning.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I've tracerouted out of my NAS to `10.8.0.1` and also got * * * right after `192.168.1.1`, however tracerouting to `4.2.2.4` returned the full path passing through `10.8.0.1` without any stars... Firewall?

Comment: Hmm, so a ping to 10.8.0.6 fails?

Comment: No. A ping to `10.8.0.6` does not fail! I've found the solution thought. Static routing inside an OpenVPN tunnel doesn't work just like that. You have to define the route in the server configuration first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read the instructions on:

https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#scope

And I've added `route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0` to the `server.conf` on my VPS and also `iroute 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0` to the correspondig `ccd` file for the client. And then I used the command `route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.8.0.6` and that was it! I could ping my `192.168.1.102` client behind my OpenVPN client from my VPS  :D

P.S: I'm still in `subnet topology` mode. I haven't tried it in the normal `p2p topology`, but I think it should work s well.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify a bit, this being something that was extremely hard for me to understand:

- On the machine that is running the OpenVPN client software, routes must be created by OpenVPN in response to `route` (no "i") directives in its configuration file. This is to ensure that the traffic is routed through the virtual `tunX` device and that OpenVPN is aware of it. If OpenVPN is acting as a router for the local subnet to which it is attached, routes are needed to "catch" the incoming traffic that is being "sent to it as a gateway," and to cause it to be tendered to OpenVPN for delivery. *(If the operating system doesn't route it through that virtual device, OpenVPN will never see it.)*
- If the destination address is not one that OpenVPN already knows about ... it is a remote subnet other than the local-address on either side ... then `iroute` (with an "i") is required to inform OpenVPN of the subnet's existence and to tell it which remote to send traffic to. (If it does not, you will see in the OpenVPN log that it has discarded the packet for this very reason.)
- All traffic routing must be "as is done for any TCP/IP router." Each and every "hop" must do the right thing. (`traceroute` is your friend.)  Furthermore, traffic originating *on* a box that's running an OpenVPN client will be perceived as having an IP-address doled out by OpenVPN for that purpose, usually `10.8.0.x`, so this address-range must be correctly routed *(everywhere ...)* as well. If the tunnel is successfully connected but you can't communicate, "you have a TCP/IP routing problem," much as you would have for any other type of router appliance.

I hope that these additional comments are useful to you.